# how to copy all of table information with dynamic vba cells in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have a table in a sheet as shown below

[image]

Also I have vba codes in all `OptionButtons`. My codes for `OptionButtons` looks like this:

```
Private Sub OptionButton11_Click()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("$J$6").Activate
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*4"
    ActiveCell.Offset(5, 0).Select

    ActiveCell.Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-7]C:R[-1]C)"
End Sub
```

And like this:

```
Private Sub
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("$J$8").Activate
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*2"
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Select

    ActiveCell.Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-7]C:R[-1]C)"
End Sub
```

I have 45 such tables on same sheet and I do not want to with code for every radio button. My code works well for 1st table but how can I copy this for rest?

I wanna do a sheet like in attachment

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to first understand what is the pattern followed by the code. If you can identify the pattern then all you have to do is use a very simply code for all the buttons.
2. Also instead of using `ActiveX Option Button`, use the `Form Control Option Button`. The reason is we can tie all the option buttons to the same code using `Assign Macro`
3. The next trick that we will use is to name the Option Button in a sequence so that we can use the number (for ex: 1 from "Option Button 1") for our calculations

Here is a very basic example on how to use multiple buttons to achieve the same functionality

Let's say our worksheet looks like this. Now what we want is whichever button we choose the cell J in the respective row should have some value.

[image]

Put this code in a module. Next in each `Option Button`, right click and click on `Assign Macro`. Choose the common code that you wrote. In this example we will choose `Sample`.

Notice how we use the `Application.Caller` to get the name of the Option Button to achieve what we want.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long

    i = Val(Trim(Replace(Application.Caller, "Option Button", "")))

    Sheet1.Range("J" & i + 1).Value = "Blah Blah Blah"
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

In your case the code can be written something like this. You have to identify the pattern and amend the below code accordingly.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim multiplier As Long

    i = Val(Trim(Replace(Application.Caller, "Option Button", "")))

    multiplier = i + 3

    With Sheet1.Range("J" & i + 5)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]" & "*" & multiplier
        .Offset(i + 5, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-7]C:R[-1]C)"
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Note**: The above can be achieved with ActiveX Controls as well but then you have to work with Array Controls as shown in [VBA – Control Arrays](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/08/05/vba-control-arrays/)

Comment: `Application.Caller` will give you the name of the option button which called the code and in `Replace(Application.Caller, "Option Button", "")` I am retrieving the number by replacing `Option Button` in `Option Button 1` EDIT: I see you have deleted your comment?

Comment: hey Siddharth, I'm very glad for your response. I'm trying understand to your response. So I can't get '(Replace(Application.Caller, "Option Button", "")' and when i write that code to my OptionButton, but it always writes in same column.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a vba code to add subroutines in loop to a module. For example if you want to add subroutines Private Sub OptionButton1(), Private Sub OptionButton2(), Private Sub OptionButton3() and so on to your Module1 then,

```
Sub AddProcedureToModule()
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim LineNum As Long
    Const DQUOTE = """" ' one " character

    Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Module1")
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

    With CodeMod

    For i = 1 To 5
        LineNum = .CountOfLines + 1
        .InsertLines LineNum, "Private Sub OptionButton" & i & "_Click()"
        LineNum = LineNum + 1
        .InsertLines LineNum, "    MsgBox " & DQUOTE & "Hello World" & DQUOTE
        LineNum = LineNum + 1
        .InsertLines LineNum, "End Sub"
    Next i

    End With
End Sub
```

This will insert the below code to your Module1

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    MsgBox "Hello World"
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    MsgBox "Hello World"
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton3_Click()
    MsgBox "Hello World"
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton4_Click()
    MsgBox "Hello World"
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton5_Click()
    MsgBox "Hello World"
End Sub
```

Comment: 1 table has 28 option buttons. So let's say for 6 tables you are asking him to replicate the code 168 times??? I wonder what will happen to his project if he has more tables ;)

Comment: for now I have 6 tables, but I will have more than 50 tables end of proejct. :)

Comment: my boss wanted from me a scoring chart for a competition. there are more than 50 projects. I will give that excel to jury.

Comment: Siddharth, may be i understood her question the wrong way. I thought she just wanted to replicate the function many times with minor changes which could be done this way in a loop